# Rails Joins with Exclude certain IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following Query which pulls out set of results based on an array of `IDs`

```
User.joins(:memberships).
     where(plan_memberships: { user_id: attendee_ids, plan_id: plan.id })
```

Now i want to do another call which excludes `attendee_ids` and then concat with the above results to retain the order of the results with `attendee_ids` first then the rest.

Is there a way to retain the order of the results based on certain IDs first and then show the remaining results?

Comment: what is `plan_memberships` ?

Comment: I'd guess that :plan_memberships is synonymous with :memberships, it looks like there may be a typo in the ticket.

Comment: yeah @AJFaraday is right :) just renamed it to `memberships` for easy usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case the best way is to retrieve results separately by two db queries.

```
common_scope = User.joins(:memberships).where(plan_memberships: { plan_id: plan.id })

excluded = common_scope.where.not(plan_memberships: { user_id: attendee_ids })
encluded = common_scope.where(plan_memberships: { user_id: attendee_ids })

all_sorted = excluded + encluded
```

`Answer to additional question:`

If you want to retrieve a certain number of records you can do it this way:

```
common_scope = User.joins(:memberships).where(plan_memberships: { plan_id: plan.id })
excluded_scope = common_scope.where.not(plan_memberships: { user_id: attendee_ids })
encluded_scope = common_scope.where(plan_memberships: { user_id: attendee_ids })

number = 3

excluded = excluded_scope.limit(number)
size = excluded.size

if size < number
  encluded = encluded_scope.limit(number - size)
  all_sorted = excluded + encluded
else
  all_sorted = excluded
end
```

Comment: oh okay. will do that :)

Comment: is there a way to add an over all limit of 3 records in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You could try injecting some SQL to cover your exclusion case.

```
User.joins(:memberships).
     where(plan_memberships: { user_id: attendee_ids, plan_id: plan.id }).
     where('plan_memberships.user_id not in (?)', banned_user_ids)
```

Note: This may be different depending on your choice of database

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySql there is an option to retain the order based on the ids you have got in an array.

```
field(user_id, [array of ids])
```

For more details, you can check here http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/